# Java 8 stream parallel reduce BiFunction accumulator

Tags: java, java-8, reduce, java-stream, binary-operators

I am learning Java 8. The most difficult thing I have to face is the Parallel Reduction. Here is the code from a example of the user @Stuart Marks I am studying with.

```
class ImmutableAverager 
{
    private final int total;
    private final int count;
    public ImmutableAverager(){this.total = 0;this.count = 0;}
   public ImmutableAverager(int total, int count)
   {
      this.total = total;
      this.count = count;
   }
   public double average(){return count > 0 ? ((double) total) / count : 0;}
   public ImmutableAverager accept(final int i)
   {
       return new ImmutableAverager(total + i, count + 1);
   }
   public ImmutableAverager combine(final ImmutableAverager other)
   {
       return new ImmutableAverager(total + other.total, count + other.count);
   }
```

The call

```
public static void main(String[] args)     
{
       System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
        .parallel()
        .reduce(new ImmutableAverager(), 
                ImmutableAverager::accept,
                ImmutableAverager::combine)
        .average());    
}
```

This produce the right results but later I checked the signature of the reduce method

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

I would understand clearly if the code would be something like:

```
.reduce(new ImmutableAverager(),(a,b)->a.accept(b),(a,b)->a.combine(b))
```

I don't understand how:

```
 ImmutableAverager::accept
```

Can convert into a `BiFunction`

My understanding is this:

```
ImmutableAverager::accept
```

is convert it in something like

```
(ImmutableAverage a)->a.accept(); //but this is a function with 1 parameter not with 2 parameters.
```

and

```
ImmutableAverager::merge
```

can convert into a `BinaryOperator`. My friend @Stuart Marks says

The methods match the function arguments to reduce so we can use method references.

Comment: Hi. Fortunately I happened to be online at the time you asked this question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a subtlety here regarding the way that arguments are shifted when this kind of method reference is used, specifically an "unbound" method reference.

Let's look at the second argument of `reduce()`. It wants

```
BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator
```

and so the signature of its abstract method is:

```
U apply(U, T)
```

(wildcard elided for brevity). The example had used a method reference `ImmutableAverager::accept` and its signature is:

```
ImmutableAverager accept(int i)
```

It **looks** like this doesn't work, because a `BiFunction` requires two arguments, whereas the `accept` method takes only one. But notice that the `accept` method is an *instance method* on the `ImmutableAverager` class, so it implicitly also takes a "receiver", that is, the object upon which this method is called. An ordinary call to this method might look like this:

```
newAverager = oldAverager.accept(i);
```

So really, the `accept` method actually takes **two** arguments even though it doesn't look like it. The first is the receiver, which is of type `ImmutableAverager`, and the second is of type `int`. The method call syntax makes it look like there's something special about the receiver, but there really isn't. It's as if this were a static method called like this:

```
newAverager = accept(oldAverager, i);
```

Now let's look at how this works with the `reduce` call. The code in question is,

```
reduce(..., ImmutableAverager::accept, ...)
```

I'm only showing the second argument here. This needs to be a `BiFunction` that takes arguments of `U` and `T` and returns a `U` as shown above. If you look at the `accept` method and treat the receiver not as something special but as an ordinary argument, it takes an argument of type `ImmutableAverager` and an argument of type `int`, and returns an `ImmutableAverager`. So `U` is inferred to be `ImmutableAverager` and `T` is inferred to be `Integer` (boxed from `int`), and the method reference here works.

The key point is, for an unbound method reference, the method reference is to an *instance method* but the method is specified using the *class name* instead of an actual instance. When this occurs, the receiver turns into the first argument of the method call.